# How to expose an array of opaque type with pybind11 and NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, api-design, pybind11

#### TL;DR

Using **pybind11**, how can I expose an array of POD struct with **NumPy**, while also having them appear to the user as nice Python objects?

#### The problem

I am exposing a **C style API** to **Python** using **pybind11**.
There are some types, implemented as simple POD struct in C, which would make more sense as opaque objects in Python. **pybind11** allows me to do that and define how the object looks like in Python.

I also want to expose a dynamically allocated array of those. Doing so using  **pybind11** and **NumPy** is possible, but I haven't found a way that's compatible with how I've already exposed the type itself.

I end up with two different Python types, which are not compatible with each other, even though the underlying C type is the same.

#### Constraints

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve unnecessary copies. Since all the data are POD, I assume it should be possible to just reinterpret the data as structs on the C side or as opaque objects on the Python side.

The C API is fixed, but I have freedom over how I design the Python API.

#### Implementation details

On the C/C++ side, the type looks like this:

```
struct apiprefix_opaque_type
{
    int inner_value;
};
```

Using **pybind11**, I'm exposing the structure as an opaque object. It's not critical that `inner_value` is not exposed, but it simply doesn't have much value for the user, and it makes more sense to have a higher level type.

```
namespace py = pybind11;

void bindings(py::module_& m)
{
    py::class_<apiprefix_opaque_type>(m, "opaque_type")
        .def(py::init([]() {
            apiprefix_opaque_type x;
            x.inner_value = -1;
            return x;
        }))
        .def("is_set", [](const apiprefix_opaque_type& x) -> bool { return x.inner_value != -1; });

    m.def("create_some_opaque", []() -> apiprefix_opaque_type {
        apiprefix_opaque_type x;
        x.inner_value = 42;
        return x;
    });
}
```

With this in place, on the Python side I have the API behaviour I want.

```
>>> a = apitest.opaque_type()
>>> a.inner_value # Demonstrating that inner_value is not exposed.
AttributeError: 'apitest.opaque_type' object has no attribute 'inner_value'
>>> a.is_set()
False
>>> b = apitest.create_some_opaque()
>>> b.is_set()
True
```

Somewhere else in the API, I have a structure containing an array of these, as a pointer and count pair. For the sake of simplicity, let's pretend it's a global variable (even though in reality, it's a member of another dynamically allocated object).

```
struct apiprefix_state
{
    apiprefix_opaque_type* things;
    int num_things;
};

apiprefix_state g_state = { nullptr, 0 };
```

This array is big enough that I care about about performance. Hence my constraint on avoiding unnecessary copies.

From Python, I want to be able to read the array, modify the array, or replace the array entirely. I think it makes more sense if whoever last set the array retained ownership over it, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here is my current attempt at exposing the array with **NumPy**.

```
void more_bindings(py::module_& m)
{
    py::class_<apiprefix_state>(m, "state")
        .def(py::init([]() {
            return g_state;
        }))
        .def("create_things",
             [](apiprefix_state&, int size) -> py::array {
                 auto arr = py::array_t<apiprefix_opaque_type>(size);
                 return std::move(arr);
             })
        .def_property(
            "things",
            [](apiprefix_state& state) {
                auto base = py::array_t<apiprefix_opaque_type>();
                return py::array_t<apiprefix_opaque_type>(state.num_things, state.things, base);
            },
            [](apiprefix_state& state, py::array_t<apiprefix_opaque_type> things) {
                state.things = nullptr;
                state.num_things = 0;
                if (things.size() > 0)
                {
                    state.num_things = things.size();
                    state.things = (apiprefix_opaque_type*)things.request().ptr;
                }
            });
}
```

Given my rudimentary understanding of memory management in Python, I strongly suspect ownership is not properly implemented.

But the problem this question is about, is that NumPy doesn't understand what `apiprefix_opaque_type` is.

```
>>> state = apitest.state()
>>> state.things
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: NumPy type info missing for struct apiprefix_opaque_type
>>>
```

If I add a dtype declaration...

```
    PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE(apiprefix_opaque_type, inner_value);
```

...now NumPy understands it, but there are now two incompatible Python types that refer to the same C type. Also, the implementation detail `inner_value` is exposed.

```
>>> state = apitest.state()
>>> state.things
array([], dtype=[('inner_value', '<i4')])
>>> state.things = state.create_things(10)
>>> a = apitest.opaque_type()
>>> a
<apitest.opaque_type object at 0x000001BABE6E72B0>
>>> state.things[0] = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'apitest.opaque_type'
>>>
```

How can I expose my array of opaque objects?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to expose the array of things then you could do something like this

```
apiprefix_opaque_type& apiprefix_state_get(apiprefix_state& s, size_t j)
{

    return s.things[j];
}

void apiprefix_state_set(apiprefix_state& s, size_t j, const apiprefix_opaque_type& o)
{
    s.things[j] = o;
}

py::class_<apiprefix_state>(m, "state")
    // ...
    .def("__getitem__", &apiprefix_state_get)
    .def("__setitem__", &apiprefix_state_set)
```

Adding range checks would obviously be a good idea. (and you can use lambdas, I just find explicit functions a bit more readable).

When you wrap `things` in a numpy array you are exposing it as a [buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html), and the structured dtype just provides information about what bytes at what offsets should be interpreted as `int`s. So you could actually write `state.things[0] = 42` above (more generally for a struct with multiple members you could assign a tuple). But it does not know how to extract an `int` from `apiprefix_opaque_type` to assign it to the field defined by the dtype.

If you want to expose `things` as a numpy array then as you've noted ownership is an important question. As implemented above, python will own any arrays created by `create_things` and manage the underlying memory. However there are a couple of issues with your setter. First

```
state.things = nullptr;
state.num_things = 0;
```

is a potential memory leak if the memory pointed to by `state.things` isn't managed by python. Secondly in this line

```
state.things = (apiprefix_opaque_type*)things.request().ptr;
```

you are referencing memory managed by python without [reference counting](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html), so there is a chance the `apiprefix_state` will be left with `things` pointing to memory that python has garbage collected.

It looks like you probably want to expose the global `g_state` which is presumable managed by C++. In this case one possible method is

```
pybind11::capsule nogc(values, [](void *f) {});
return pybind11::array_t<apiprefix_opaque_type>(
    { g_state.num_things },
    { sizeof(apiprefix_opaque_type) },
    g_state.things,
    nogc
);
```

Alternatively you could use the [buffer protocol](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html#buffer-protocol) directly or a memory view.

If you do want to always refer to a global state then it's unusual to return it from the initializer

```
.def(py::init([]() { return g_state; }))
```

normally it would be something like

```
.def_static("get_instance", ... )
```

but note this doesn't quite do what you want as it will copy `g_state`.